# Считывание числа с консоли - как спрашивать пользователя пока он не введет что нужно?

Tags: java

Собственно вопрос как начинающего программиста на Java, 
в ниже указанном коде выходит ошибка при вводе любой буквы, знаю что это целочисленный тип, но мне нужно что бы при вводе буквы цикл так же задавал тот же вопрос и ждал от пользователя того что бы он ввел число а не букву! и при проверке числа вышел из цикла...

```
int age;
do {
  System.out.print(+age+"Не верный ввод данных, повторите еще раз: ");
  age =   myScanner.nextInt();
}while (age <= 150);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте не так. Вводите строку и пробуйте сконвертировать её в `int`. Если не получается — сообщайте пользователю всё, что про него думаете.

```
int age = -1;
while (true)
{
    System.out.println("Возраст?");
    // вводим строку
    String line = myScanner.nextLine();
    try  
    {
        // пробуем сконсертировать в число
        age = Integer.parseInt(line);
        // если не получится, мы вылетим в catch
        // проверяем значение
        if (age > 150)
            System.out.println("Больше 150 не бывает!");
        else
            break; // всё хорошо, завершаем цикл ввода
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // если введено не число, мы окажемся тут
        System.out.println("Это вообще не число");
    }
}
```

Comment: да если бы я знал как, я же написал что начинающий....дело в том что дальше по коду мне нужно вычислять целочисленные типы данных, и то что пользователь введет число оно тоже считается! а буква мне не нужна совсем.

Comment: @Andrey: Снова обновил ответ.

Comment: Ого! все работает! Круто!!! мда мне ще учить и учиться...(((( Спасибо вам!!! я тут первый раз на сайте... щас попробую найти что бы поставить лайк или что то в этом роде в вашу сторону... :)

Comment: Учитесь! :) В любом случае, ввод строки и разбор её потом — хорошая идея, запомните её на будущее.